# как найти позицию Кнопки и задать в CGPoint?

Tags: ios, swift, анимация, tableview, uibutton

Я изучал метод анимации, и со всего пространства view задавал позицию откуда движется объекта и его конечная точка.Я немного не  понял как найти и задать точку CGPoint кнопки.Чтоб откуда вылетали объекты.Зашел в настройках storyboard узнал позицию и их в писал точку откуда будут вылетать отбьекты.А как подругому сделать? и еще я указываю view.Я сделал метод в примере другом проекте.У меня TableviewСell. Подскажите я в методе должен вместо view? указать contentView?

```
import UIKit

class CoreGraphic: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            likeButton.layer.cornerRadius = likeButton.frame.width/2
            likeButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {


         likeButton.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(likeTap)))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // let curvedView = CurvedView(frame: view.frame)
       // curvedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
       // view.addSubview(curvedView)



    }




    @objc func likeTap() {
        (0...10).forEach { (_)  in

            generateAnimationView()

         }
    }

    fileprivate func generateAnimationView() {
        let image = drand48() > 0.5 ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sampdoriaOne") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "villarrealTwo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let demision = 20+drand48()*10
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: demision, height: demision)


        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.path = customPath().cgPath
        animation.duration = 2 * drand48() * 3
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        let nameString = kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: nameString)

        imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        view.addSubview(imageView)


    }


}
    func customPath()->UIBezierPath {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 224))
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 200)
        let randomYShift = 200+drand48()*300
        let controlP1 = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200-randomYShift)
        let controlP2 = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300+randomYShift)

        path.addCurve(to: endPoint, controlPoint1: controlP1, controlPoint2: controlP2)
        return path
    }



class CurvedView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // saddasd dsad dsad asdas
        let path = customPath()
        path.lineWidth = 3
        path.stroke()

    }

}
```

Comment: Объясните доступнее цель, которую необходимо достичь. При нажатии на кнопку из нее должны вылетать изображения?

Comment: Да у меня это работает.Я имел виду мне нужно указать точку CGPoint этой кнопки.Я ее то вычислил в сторибоарде и указал координаты, а как кодом через frame и т.д. ее указать.Если вдруг будет меняться размер дивайса  , чтоб точка оставалась не измененной.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения точки касания необходимо взять позицию события:

```
@IBAction func testAction(_ sender: UIButton, for event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = event.touches(for: sender)?.first {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: view)
        print(touchLocation)
    }
}
```

Демонстрация (добавляю черную UIView 2x2px в точке касания):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо . хорошая статья, но я имел виду другое и я понял как сделать. Я задал кнопка.layer.position.x и y .